# how to plot cumulative distribution plot in R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, distribution, cumulative-frequency

I have a data and I want to plot cumulative distribution of this.
My data is:

```
 dput(gene_snp_distance[1:20, c(1:3)])
structure(list(distance = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 
7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 11000, 12000, 13000, 14000, 15000, 16000, 
17000, 18000, 19000, 20000), all_snps = c(10, 11.8, 13.6, 15.4, 
17.2, 19, 20.8, 22.6, 24.4, 26.2, 28, 29.8, 31.6, 33.4, 35.2, 
37, 38.8, 40.6, 42.4, 44.2), gtex_snps = c(12, 14.3, 16.6, 18.9, 
21.2, 23.5, 25.8, 28.1, 30.4, 32.7, 35, 37.3, 39.6, 41.9, 44.2, 
46.5, 48.8, 51.1, 53.4, 56.2)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

And this is what I tried:

```
plot(gene_snp_distance$distance, gene_snp_distance$all_snps)
```

But I want to plot a graph like this:
wherein the first blue plot represent all_Snps and red represents gtex_Snps.
Does anyone know how to plot this similar graph.

[image]
My plotted graph look like this:
[image]
But I want it to represent a bar for each distance and do in one graph for both all_snps and gtex_snps like a bar graph on top of each other.

Does anyone know how to plot a similar graph like this one.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want. Since `all_Snps` is not defined in your data, I can only guess that you would like to plot the cumulative sum of `gtex_snps` next to `gtex_snps` itself.

```r
library(tidyverse)

p <- gene_snp_distance |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = matches("snps"),
               names_to = "type", 
               values_to = "value") |> 
  ggplot(aes(distance, value, fill = type))

p + geom_col()
```

[image]

```r
p + geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

where

```r
gene_snp_distance <- structure(list(distance = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 
                                  7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 11000, 12000, 13000, 14000, 15000, 16000, 
                                  17000, 18000, 19000, 20000), all_snps = c(10, 11.8, 13.6, 15.4, 
                                                                            17.2, 19, 20.8, 22.6, 24.4, 26.2, 28, 29.8, 31.6, 33.4, 35.2, 
                                                                            37, 38.8, 40.6, 42.4, 44.2), gtex_snps = c(12, 14.3, 16.6, 18.9, 
                                                                                                                       21.2, 23.5, 25.8, 28.1, 30.4, 32.7, 35, 37.3, 39.6, 41.9, 44.2, 
                                                                                                                       46.5, 48.8, 51.1, 53.4, 56.2)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives an error                                                                      
   Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: I am sorry. I have edited my post to include all_snps in dput value. I want to first plot bar graph of all snps and on top or side of that gtex_snps

Comment: I am referring to your data as `df` in my code. So you will have to either rename your dataset accordingly or replace `df` from my code with the name of the object that holds your data.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your naming conventions (the dataset is now called `gene_snp_distance`) and the new column in your data. I also include two options, either a stacked or a dodged bar chart. Does this do what you want?

Comment: hello, yes, this one works. I want to ask if you don't mind can you explain the part of code with respect to p. I don't understand it. I am not very familiar with tidyverse and trying to learn R.